# Missing logic with Map / Combine / Reduce, about how to take trace of something

Tags: java, hadoop, dictionary, logic, reducers

I'm trying to do different staff using map/reducer than the previous one I was doing.

I have now a file in input like this one:

```
1 50000 2015 pc technology 
2 15424 1998 mouse technology 
3 78420 2010 pen technology 
4 8452 2000 pen stationery
5 4125 2000 pen stationery
```

id, price, year, item, type

The thing that I'm trying to do is to calculate the average price for a particular item of a particular type, for every type and for every year where that particular item has been sold. So, making an example, I started to do this stuff for pens. What is the average price for pens during 2000 ? In my example there are two kinds of pen (digital for pc, and standard ones), so I like to have an output like:

```
pen stationery 6288 2000
pen technology 78420 2010
```

The problem I have is that I don't know how to do it... I know how to calculate the avg by using a combiner/reducer, but I don't know how to take trace of the year and the items...
My logic is this: check if the item is a pen, then take trace of the year and the price for that pen, and calculate the average with this data. But I don't know how to do it.
Any help is really appreciate, thank you

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.StringTokenizer;
import java.util.*;

import org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration;
import org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path;
import org.apache.hadoop.io.IntWritable;
import org.apache.hadoop.io.Text;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Mapper;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Reducer;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.input.FileInputFormat;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.output.FileOutputFormat;

public class Draft2 {

     public static class TokenizerMapper extends Mapper<Object, Text, Text, Text>{

     private Text word = new Text(); 
     private Text word2 = new Text(); 

     public void map(Object key, Text value, Context context) throws IOException, InterruptedException {

         String[] tokens = value.toString().split(",");

         String price = "";
         String item = "";
         String typ = "";
         String year = "";

         if(tokens.length >= 2)
             price = tokens[1];

         if(tokens.length >= 3)
             year = tokens[2];

         if (tokens.length >=5)
             typ = tokens[4];

         if (tokens.length >=14)
             item = tokens[13];


         if(!item.isEmpty())
         {
             word.set(item + "|" + year);
             word2.set(price + "|" + typ);
             context.write(word, word2);
         }
    }
  }

  public static class MeanCombiner extends Reducer <Text,Text,Text,Text> {
      private Text word = new Text();
      private Text word2 = new Text();

      public void combine(Text key, Iterable<Text> values, Context context) throws IOException, InterruptedException {
          int sum = 0;
          int counter = 0;

          final Iterator<Text> itr = values.iterator();
          String[] strs = key.toString().split("|");
          final String[] tokens = values.toString().split("|");

          String item = strs[0];
          String typ = tokens[1];
          String type = "pen";
          String year = strs[1];
          Boolean found = false;


       for (Text val: values) {
          String[] strs = key.toString().split("|");
          final String[] tokens = values.toString().split("|");                
          String item= strs[0];
          String typ = tokens[1];
          String type = "pen";
          String year = strs[1];

          if (typ.equals(type)) {
              found = true;
          //don't know how to go on       

          }

          /*this part is for the average but with wrong data*/
          while (itr.hasNext()) {
                if (typ.equals(type)) {
                    final String price = tokens[0];
                    final int value = Integer.parseInt(price);
                    counter++;
                    sum += value;
                  }
          }

          final int average = sum/counter;

      String avg = Integer.toString(average);
      String count = Integer.toString(counter);
          word.set(key.toString());
          word2.set(avg + "|" + count);
          context.write(word, word2);
         }
  }

  /*The reducer is incomplete*/
  public static class MeanReducer extends Reducer<Text,Text,Text,Text> {

    private Text word = new Text();
    private Text word2 = new Text();

    public void reduce(Text key, Iterable<Text> values, Context context
                       ) throws IOException, InterruptedException {


    word.set(k);
    word2.set();
    context.write(word, word2);

    }
  }

  public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    Configuration conf = new Configuration();
    Job job = Job.getInstance(conf, "Draft2");
    job.setJarByClass(Draft2.class);
    job.setCombinerClass(MeanCombiner.class);
    job.setMapperClass(TokenizerMapper.class);
    job.setReducerClass(MeanReducer.class);
    job.setMapOutputKeyClass(Text.class);
    job.setMapOutputValueClass(Text.class);
    job.setOutputKeyClass(Text.class); 
    job.setOutputValueClass(Text.class); 
    FileInputFormat.addInputPath(job, new Path(args[0]));
    FileOutputFormat.setOutputPath(job, new Path(args[1]));
    System.exit(job.waitForCompletion(true) ? 0 : 1);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Combiner should not be used while calculating the averages.

I will explain the solution assuming that following is your input:

```
1 50000 2015 pc technology 
2 15424 1998 mouse technology 
3 78420 2010 pen technology 
4 8452 2000 pen stationery
5 4125 2000 pen stationery
```

**Mapper:**

1. Parse each record by splitting on blank (" ")
2. For each record, emit (key,value) as (year|item|type, price). Combining (year|item|type) will give a unique key for each record. For e.g for the record, "5 4125 2000 pen stationery", you will emit key as: "2000|pen| stationery and value as: 4125.

So the output from the mapper will be:

```
2015|pc|technology    50000 
1998|mouse|technology 15424 
2010|pen|technology   78420 
2000|pen|stationery   8452 
2000|pen|stationery   4125
```

**Reducer:**

1. For each key, calculate the sum and then the average.
2. Emit the average, along with other details

For e.g. following keys will come to the same reducer:

```
2000|pen|stationery   8452 
2000|pen|stationery   4125
```

Output will be:

```
pen stationery 6288 2000
```